# install grails web flow plugin in grails 2.4.0

Tags: grails

im trying to install grails web flow plugin version 2.0.8.1 but im getting errors when run grails compile in order to install the plugin, not success with version 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT suggested by Greame Rocher in this post http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/weblow-2-0-8-1-broken-when-moving-to-Grails-2-4-0-td4656969.html

any solution?

thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

compile `:webflow:2.1.0` in your build `config.groovy` in your `grails 2.2.4` application. It'll run and execute.

Answer (score 0):

If it won't compile under Grails 2.4.0 then quite clearly it's not compatible with Grails 2.4.0. This shouldn't be too surprising because version 2.1.0 (which should eventually be compatible with Grails 2.4.0) is still only a SNAPSHOT. I would reply to Graeme on the mailing list and/or open a JIRA ticket detailing the compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide feedback here with the compilation error you are seeing: https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPWEBFLOW-93

Comment: I just shared compilations error message trying to install both plugin version